# betweenness in iGraph (R) produces "0" for every node

Tags: r, igraph

Using iGraph (1.0.1) for R in OS X, I imported a two-column set of interactions of parasites and hosts and converted into a graph object

```
    puro=read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    Borrelia=graph.data.frame(puro,directed=TRUE)

    > vcount(Borrelia)
    [1] 372
    > ecount(Borrelia)
    [1] 10938
```

However, when trying to calculate betweenness like this:

```
    V(Borrelia)$between <- betweenness(Borrelia, normalized = FALSE, nobigint=FALSE)
```

the result is 0 for every node:

```
    V(Borrelia)$between[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    [98] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

    [195] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

    [292] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I calculated weights

```
    E(Borrelia)$weight <- (runif(ecount(Borrelia)))
```

and included weight=NULL in betweenness above to use weights, but it does not changes the result.
It is obvious that I am doing something wrong, but I cannot find the mistake.

Comment: Did you try `V(Borrelia)$between <- igraph::betweenness(Borrelia, V(Borrelia), normalized = FALSE, nobigint=FALSE)`?

Comment: This would be a better question if you posted code that created a small example. There is no way we can get at your computer's directory.